# Mapping without KVC , RestKit version:0.27.0

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have a JSON data without a key on the top level, I need to POST it to our server, but how could I map that using RestKit (version: 0.27.0):

```
e.g.
[
{ "title": "RestKit Object Mapping Intro",
  "body": "This article details how to use RestKit object mapping...",
  "author": {
      "name": "Blake Watters",
      "email": "blake@restkit.org"
  },
  "publication_date": "7/4/2011"
}
]
```

PS: I've seen some workaround on this issue, but unfortunately, none of them could work for the newest version 0.27.0.

Thanks in advance